# Trying to ONLY add group write permissions without affecting other group permissions

Tags: linux, chmod

Ok, this should be so simple. I have a large site with many folders and files. Interspersed within all of those files are files which need to be executable, so I do not want to remove those permissions. I also do not want to add executable permissions where they are not warranted.

What I do want to do is to add group write permissions to the whole site without changing other permissions. What I need is a chmod operator which 'leaves the permission as is.' So for example, if the operator which doesn't change the persmission was "~" then I could use

$chmod -R g=rw~ foldername

...and thus I would add group Write permissions across the site without changing the executable permissions.

I just can't find documentation on actual operator which functions like "~" in my above example. I thought using +,- was the trick but I must be missing something on the syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `chmod -R g+w foldername` not do what you want?  Or `chmod -R g+rw foldername` if you need to add group read permissions too.

Comment: Yes it does! I was apparently misreading the syntax instructions. Thankya very much!

Comment: @ottomeister you should add this as an answer so that you can get the benefit of the many upvotes that it deserves :)